# GraphicsMagick (GM) resize into square without changing ratio and add background

Tags: javascript, lambda, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, gm

I'm trying to get GraphicsMagick to resize my various images into a standard square. The input is always variable - vertical, horizontal images, different sizes etc.

I want to basically have:
- A white background canvas @ 600px x 600px
- The image sits in the center of that canvas @ 500px x 500px

I've tried [so many from the docs](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html) but I can't get it working correctly.

This is what I have working so far (JavaScript):

```
gm(content)
  .autoOrient()
  .resize(600, 600)
  .gravity('Center')
  .extent([600, 600])
  .background('#FFFFFF')
  .flatten();
```

And it just comes out the correct width, but keeps the ratio so for a rectangle, it comes out at 600px wide and 240px high (as it kept the ratio).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the extent example from the GM website? It may be as simple as putting the background before the extent.

Comment: @Bonzo No luck unfortunately. I tried resize > gravity > background > extent but still comes out without 500px height.

Comment: @Bonzo Okay so my issue was that I passed in width & height into extent as an array rather than straight params... rookie error. Although no errors thrown which is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my issue was simply that I set `extent` as an array. Final solution:

```
gm(content)
  .autoOrient()
  .resize(550, 550)
  .gravity('Center')
  .background('#FFFFFF')
  .extent(600, 600)
  .flatten();
```